# count all the distinct records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count all the distinct records in a table name with a single query and also without using any sub-query.

My code is

```
select count ( distinct *) from table_name
```

It gives an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '*'.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Why can't you use a sub-query?

Comment: use select distinct count(*) from table_name

Comment: You can't put *, you need to have a column name there. That's the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [table_name]) A
```

Comment: I don't want to use the subquery.

Comment: Why don't you want to use that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that if you don't want to use a subquery, the only way to achieve that is replacing `*` with a concatenation of the columns in your table

```
select count(distinct concat(column1, column2, ..., columnN))
from   table_name
```

To avoid undesired behaviours (like the concatenation of 1 and 31 becoming equal to the concatenation of 13 and 1) you could add a reasonable separator

```
select count(distinct concat(column1, '$%&£', column2, '$%&£', ..., '$%&£', columnN)
from   table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE.

```
 ;WITH CTE AS
  (
  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TableName
  )
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM CTE
```

Hope this query gives you what you required.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you cannot use `DISTINCT` with `*`. Also it is good practice to use a column name instead of the `*`, like a unique key / primary key of the table.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id )
  FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct Name , count(Name) from TableName
group by Name
having count(Name)=1
select @@rowcount
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue involving a query that had multiple joins to tables and I could not simply do count(distinct *) or count(distinct alias.*).
My solution was to create a string made up of the key columns I cared about and count them.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT person.first || '~' || person.last)
from person;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `DISTINCT` keyword, you need to specify column name on which bases you want to get distinct records.

Example:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT Column-Name) FROM table_name
```

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to be very explicative ;)

Comment: Sorry, it was another text when I answered. @StefanoZanini